# How to make json format like that?

Tags: php

I Need json response in this format `{"tgas": ["tag1", "tag2" , "tag3"]}`. But currenly it returns this in response. ``` {"title":"Post Title", "tgas":"tag1,tag2,tag3"}. Here is my php code

```
<?php
$response = array(
            'title' => $title,
            'plot'=> strip_tags($description),
            'storline'=> strip_tags($storyline),
            'tgas'=> ($tagsoutput) //"tgas":"tag1,tag2,tag3"
            );
            $rt = json_encode($response, true);
```

Comment: rtm [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: Can You answer it please ? I'm new to php.

Comment: Your friend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71895723/how-to-put-csv-in-tags-input?

Comment: @u_mulder maybe one of them is the sender and the other is the receiver? Really it looks like AbhishekJoshi there was tasked with inserting that response into an input field, and so Rahul FYI, make sure you coordinate these devops with Joshi so you have your API spec clear and don't have to be converting stuff all over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is likely how you are adding tagsoutput which is not visible in your example.
It should be something like this:

$tagsoutput = array("tag1","tag2");

If $tagsoutput is defined already then you can split the string inline:

'tgas'=> preg_split ("/,/", $tagsoutput),

with trailing whitespace:

'tgas'=> preg_split ("/,\s/", $tagsoutput),

OR

if there is never whitespace:

'tgas'=> explode (",", $tagsoutput),

to trim whitespace:

'tgas'=> array_map('trim',explode (",", $tagsoutput)),

Comment: tags is a string in this format ```tag1, tag2, tag3``` and i can't make changes in this.

Comment: updated my answer to include the simple split. Basically you need your variable to become an array to get the result you want. You might need to trim and do other processing too. preg_split lets you put in regex to handle the whitespace. With explode you can use an arraymap

Comment: Or simply `preg_split ('/,\s*/',` to strip white-space if it exists.

Comment: Agreed. It's much better to use an asterisk as you may not know what you are getting (unless you get to write that other bit of code).

Answer (score 1):

this is the way to do it:

```
<?php
$response = array(
              'title' => $title,
              'plot'=> strip_tags($description),
              'storline'=> strip_tags($storyline),
              'tgas'=> explode(',', $tagsoutput)
            );
            $rt = json_encode($response, true);
```